# Ruby flash messages with javascript won't appear

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use my flash messages with some javascript functionality, but I'm having trouble with displaying the messages upon user sign-in and sign out. What might the problem be?

This is in the `application.html.erb` of my rails app.

```
<!-- Flash Messages -->
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    Messenger().post({
      message: flash[:notice],
    })
    </script>
<% elsif flash[:error] %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    Messenger().post({
      message: flash[:error],
    })
  </script>
<% else %>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:alert] %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
<% end %>
<!-- /Flash Messages -->
```

I'm using javascript files in my assets folder. Hopefully when this is all done the messages will appear on the bottom right instead of the default top of the page.

Comment: `flash[:error]` is a ruby/rails thing. It doesn't make sense in javascript land (where you try to use it)

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose between `<%=` and `%>` both `flash[:notice]` and `flash[:error]` messages:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    Messenger().post({
      message: <%= flash[:notice] %>
    })
  </script>
<% elsif flash[:error] %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    Messenger().post({
      message: <%= flash[:error] %>
    })
  </script>
<% else %>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:alert] %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. I tries doing it without it, but it didn't work in both instances.